# How to write less code with Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am testing the code density of Python and Haskell. So I decided to write a program to solve equations of the form ax^2+bx+c=0 where a<>0. In Python this takes five lines:

```
import cmath

def secondgrade(a,b,c):
     d=b**2-4*a*c
     return ((-b+cmath.sqrt(d))/2*a,(-b-cmath.sqrt(d))/2*a)
```

In Haskell which is supposed to be more concise and less verbose it took me twelve lines:

```
import Data.Complex

csqrt :: Double->Complex Double
csqrt a = if a<0 then 0.0 :+ sqrt(abs(a)) else sqrt(a) :+ 0.0

secondgrade :: Double->Double->Double->(Complex Double,Complex Double)
secondgrade a b c = let d = b^2 - 4*a*c
                    denominator=2*a :+ 0
                    b'=(-b) :+ 0
                    solution1=b'+(csqrt d)
                    solution2=b'-(csqrt d)
                 in (solution1/denominator,solution2/denominator)
```

Is there any solution with fewer lines and without losing in readability?

Comment: "Haskell which is supposed to be more concise and less verbose" - *please back up such claims*.

Comment: You're comparing extremely dense one-liner to a clearer broken up expression. Also that's really bad example to compare expressiveness of these two languages, especially that Python is really close to Haskell when it comes to lightweightness of syntax and expressiveness in general.

Comment: So in summary the premise is wrong, the perception is wrong, and there is no problem.

Comment: `secondgrade a b c = let d = b^2 - 4*a*c in ((d**0.5 - b)/2*a, (-(d**0.5) - b)/2*a)` Works with any instance of `Floating`, including `Complex Double`

Comment: @NiklasB, your version is still way too long, not to mension it's wrong (it has `/2*a` instead of `/(2*a)`). Here is an improved one, without code duplication! :D `secondgrade a b c=join(***)(\q->(q*(b^2-4*a*c)**0.5-b)/2/a)(1,-1)`

Comment: @Rotsor: Haha, shouldn't have blindly pasted OP's Python code here :D Nice job!

Comment: @Rotsor: Now that I think of it, the `join (***)` is a tricky one. Took me some time to figure out...

Comment: 6 characters shorter yet! `secondgrade a b c=let q=b/2/a;d=(q^2-c/a)**0.5 in(d-q,-d-q)`

Comment: python code is about 94 chars long whereas haskell's about 60. any doubts about its conciseness ? :)

Comment: Sorry for spam, but 1-character reduction is too important! `secondgrade a b c=(d-q,-d-q)where q=b/2/a;d=(q^2-c/a)**0.5`

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that the Haskell solution you currently have is better and more readable than your python version. You *could* rewrite the Haskell one to match the python version as follows:

```
import Data.Complex
secondgrade :: Double->Double->Double->(Complex Double,Complex Double)
secondgrade a b c = ((((-b) :+ 0)+(csqrt d))/(2*a :+ 0), (((-b) :+ 0)-(csqrt d))/(2*a :+ 0))
  where d = b^2 - 4*a*c
        csqrt a = if a<0 then 0.0 :+ sqrt(abs(a)) else sqrt(a) :+ 0.0
```

Of course, reducing the number of lines in code seems very second grade to me. Good code is easy to read and shouldn't require deciphering.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The Haskell version is longer because of having to define `csqrt` and make some conversions explicit. Also the type signature, but that's optional anyway. Not really something to lose sleep over.

Comment: @C.A. McCann: You can also use `**0.5`, can't you? I think you can write that function in a fully polymorphic way in two lines or so.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Yes, but that's only half of it. It's also converting the `Double` to `Complex Double`. If you use complex numbers everywhere to begin with it'd look like the Python version.

Comment: Yeah but conversion is as simple as `(:+0)`